# Browse Nginx Source Code in Eclipse CDT

Tags: eclipse, nginx

I'm trying to browse nginx source code in Eclipse CDT.

I followed the instructions on net, download the source code, execute ./configure && make, and import as an existing "Makefile Project" into Eclipse.

Fortunately I got the code jumping stuff (Ctrl+Click) right, but what bothers me is that Eclipse keeps reporting "Type 'ngx_int_t' could not be resolved.", which results in a lot of error signs in the directory view and the file itself.

How to cure this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I just figured out what the problem was: there are some functions in nginx source code that has `ngx_int_t` return type and are declared as follows:

```
ngx_int_t
<function name>
```

Apparently Eclipse doesn't like this line-breaking declaration. So I used Command+Click (i.e. Ctrl+Click) on `ngx_int_t` and Eclipse showed me all the places where such declaration was present, then I deleted the line-break between `ngx_int_t` and function name and now Eclipse doesn't yell this error.

Comment: Could you explain why the error of 'function declaration' affect the typedef not to work?